# Django AWS MySQL

Tags: django

I tried to deploy my application on AWS, but I'm having problems!
First, when trying to put MySQL data in settings.py, a problem appears:

```
"Unknown MySQL server host 'myapp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

I tried with other databases (Postgresql and Oracle) and they worked, but mysql did not.

Does anyone know how to solve? I would be grateful. Gratitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm, your setting file should be like below:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'xxx',
    'USER': 'xxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
    'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```